# Failed: read error on entry #1 line, column 25: extraneous " field 0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import

Tags: excel, mongodb, csv, xls, mongoimport

I try to import an excel csv file into using directly mongodbimport on command prompt. But I get an error. I searched about it on google and stackoverflow and I couldn't fine a solution for my issue. Would you mind to helping me?

Here is the steps I try to do on Command Prompt;

1- C:\Users\I>cd C:Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin

2- C:Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin>mongoimport --db datafilename --collection datafilename --type csv --file datafilename.csv --headerline

or I write this

mongoimport -d datafilename -c datafilename --type csv --file datafilename.csv --headerline

After this two steps I get this error:

Failed: read error on entry #1 line, column 25: extraneous " field

0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.

```
 C:\Users\I>cd C:Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin

 C:Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin>mongoimport --db datafilename --collection datafilename --type csv --file datafilename.csv --headerline

 Failed: read error on entry #1 line, column 25: extraneous " field

 0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

---

```
 C:\Users\I>cd C:Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin

 C:Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin>mongoimport -d datafilename -c datafilename --type csv --file datafilename.csv --headerline

 Failed: read error on entry #1 line, column 25: extraneous " field

 0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

Comment: That error message seems to be complaining about the content of the csv file.